# is com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl#newDurationDayTime broken?

Tags: java

This:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl sun = new com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl();
final long aTime = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(32)
System.err.println(sun.newDurationDayTime(aTime));
```

will print `P1DT0H0M0.000S`, or `0` months and `1` day if I use `getMonths` and `getDays` respectively.

I realize the months should not be set given what's said in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newDurationDayTime(long))

> whose lexical representation contains only day, hour, minute, and second components.

So `months` being `0` seems fine, but the number of days in that case should be `32`.

If I use `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl` I get the expected results, `32` days or `P32DT0H0M0.000S`.

Is the com.sum version broken, or is there something in the contract that is not mention that the plain xerces implementation is not strict about where that method cannot be used for durations >= one month?

---

Edit:

I can see in `DurationDayTimeImpl` w/in com.sum the constructor used in this case seems to get the duration correct.  After the call to `super` the months are `1` and the days are `1`.  But then after canonicalizing the time component, the years and months are wiped out:

```
    this.years = null;
    this.months = null;
```

This is how it ends up with a value of a single day.  I can see why it clears those values given what the javadocs say, but that seems like a bug to not down convert those into days.

The plain xerces impl simply divides off the individual components; the com.sun version uses `XMLGregorianCalendar`.